# myvector does not name a type

Tags: c++, vector

#### main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "normal.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

#### normal.h

```
#ifndef NORMAL_H
     #define NORMAL_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
vector < int > myvector;
myvector.push_back(12);//does not name a type
#endif
```

I know I need to somehow include `vector<int> myvector` in `main.cpp` but can't figure the way. I've looked at my previous programs and didn't need to include anything in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Why are you declaring your vector in a separate `.h` instead of the `.cpp`? Declare it and use it right in the `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code 
`myvector.push_back(12);` is not inside any function. Outside of functions you may only declare (and possibly initialize) variables, you cannot put other code.

So, even though you can declare your vector in the `.h` file (probably to have it available in many files) you should move this line inside the `main()` or some other function.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple.